# Auto only once!

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I'm using a jcarousel I've set it to display the images automatically every 1 second. I did this by setting the auto property.

I've been looking at ways to do this only ONCE, that is I only one to go through the images once. Not infinite. I changed the wrap property to null, and it stops repeating it, but i would like for it to go through all the images then to the first and stop there (at the beginning of the cycle if so to say).

Any hints welcome!

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda odd that it doesn't support a `repeat` property.

Not having used jCarousel before, I'm only speculating that this might work (from reading the [documentation](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/)).

In your configuration, set the `wrap` property to 'last'. Using the `itemLastOutCallback` function (which is apparently called after the last item is displayed) set the `wrap` property to 'null'.